# Removing user entry from /etc/passwd

Tags: linux, sed

I am trying to create a `sed` statement to remove `ftp` and other users which we don't need on our Redhat 5/6 servers.  I am trying to create a `sed` pattern so I can find for example `ftp` and it removes the whole line. The following is what I have but it's not working:

```
sed '/ftp/d'  /etc/passwd
```

Comment: Homework problem?

Comment: @mdpc No.  I am trying to resolve security issues and one stack of servers have ftp and other user entries in /etc/passwd but there are no users on the servers hence need to put this in my script so entries can be removed.  There are many other issues which I am trying to resolve on one server and then pushing to others with my hardening script.

Answer (score 5):

As hinted at in [Christopher's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132767/removing-user-entry-from-etc-passwd#comment212841_132767), removing a user's entry from `/etc/passwd` does not remove all traces of the user from the system. You're better off doing something like:

```
userdel ftp
```

or

```
for user in <list of users>;do
    userdel $user
done
```

You can also supply the `-r` switch (as in `userdel -r bob`) in order to remove the contents of the user's home directory as well. Careful, though, that would be a **terrible idea** in case you're deleting system users as these usually have homes that live under `/etc` and `/var/lib`.

Comment: Thanks!  I have added the reason for doing this.  There are no valid users on the server just entries in /etc/passwd. I have another pattern which is using the mentioned "i" but for some reason I didn't notice that I was missing it.  I guess I needed a second eye to catch it.  Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to either be root or use `sudo` to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Red Hat should use the GNU Sed so this should do the trick.

```
sed -i '/pattern_you_are_matching/d' /dir/whatever-the-file
```

Note that -i option is only available in GNU Sed.

Comment: `-i` is also available in FreeBSD (added in 2002 shortly before GNU's) and derivatives (like Apple OS/X `sed`) though the extension is a required argument, so it's `sed -i '' /pattern/...` there. That `-i` is inspired from `perl`'s equivalent option.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas - Thank you for that notification. But for example on Solaris there is no -i option. So on Solaris this requirement would require something like this: _sed '/match_something/d' file.txt > new_file.txt_

Answer (score 1):

you have to add -i option:

```
sed -i '/ftp/d' /etc/passwd
```

-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

```
          edit files in place (makes backup if extension  supplied).   The
          default  operation  mode  is  to  break symbolic and hard links.
          This can be changed with --follow-symlinks and --copy.
```